# MySQL: retrieved data has wrong timezone

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know why a retrieved DateTime object's timezone doesn't reflect the timezone of the server (`UTC`)? I have a server that uses `UTC`, and the timestamp is correctly in its timezone, but when I query and retrieve this, the DateTime object's `timezone` is changed to `US/Pacific`, which is where I live.

So, when I do `$temp->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('US/Pacific'));`, the timestamp doesn't change because it's alrady in `US/Pacific`. I've Tried other timezones in its place, and they change accordingly.

Any ideas?

EDIT: phpinfo() displays `America/Los_Angeles`.. is that why I"m getting the Pacific timezone in the retrieved data? Basically, I want to be able to convert whaterver timezone the source used into my timezone, so it displays to the user properly.

Comment: WHat does `phpinfo();` say about the configured timezone _for php_?

Comment: What do you get from `date_default_timezone_get`?

Comment: See [PHP, MySQL and Time Zones](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15233922).

Comment: phpinfo() shows America/Los_Angeles. Ah, egg's link is shedding some light on the issue. Does this mean I can't use the string `US/Pacific` to convert this retrieved DateTime object into my timezone?

Comment: If your server uses UTC throughout, and you'd like to keep using that, setting the default timezone for PHP & MySQL to that seems the logical choice.