# How to work with time zone and how to store them in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

Can somebody please explain to me how to work with time zones? How should I store the time zone in the database and how to do the math to figure out the time?

How can I sort activities by time zone?

Thanks

Comment: Click on this link and then close this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768380/php-mysql-and-time-zones

Comment: I'd like to flag the above comment about 100 more times to emphasize that answer.