# Saving to MySQL TIME and DATE data types through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, type-conversion

I need to store date in DATE type and time in TIME type in a MySQL database table. I have found many ways such as formatting and converting from unix time etc. but whats the most straightforward, simplest way to create data to store as DATE and TIME types in MySQL when using PHP.

Comment: what many ways did you find? what are you considering straightforward/simple (sounds like an opinion based question?), and why did you not choose one of the methods you found?

Comment: I like this question btw, and so does google. However, I suggest others look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768380/php-mysql-and-time-zones?rq=1) for a great answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the date/time type you're having in PHP.
If you have a timestamp, e.g. `$timestamp`, then

```
$mySqlDate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
$mySqlTime = date('H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

In case you have a DateTime object `$datetime`

```
$mySqlDate = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
$mySqlTime = $datetime->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: I'm generating the time using php function time(), its value I have to generate and store, not a valued passed in any format. How to apply this if I generate the datetime using time() in php? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much, answer was here all the time :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use a [date/datetime data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html).

Then insert the data into it using a `YYYY-MM-DD` format for dates, or a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format for datetime.

This will also let you use the lovely MySQL time functions quite easily like to insert the current time into a datetime field, you can use:

```
insert into yourTable (DateTimeColumn) values (now());
```

Using PHP you can pretty easily make the required format from strings, date objects and just about anything.

Comment: This is for the purpose of maintaining activity log table. I need to query activity by date or specific time duration on any date, that is why I use separate date and time columns with DATE and TIME types in MySQL. Thanks

Comment: Or am I doing the entire thing in a bad inefficient way?

Comment: It really depends on your actual requirements. For most, I would be happy with a datetime, but there is a TIME datatype that is available as well which you can use quite easily for time info only.

Comment: thanks, right now I get the time details using time(), i want to convert that to both DATE and TIME types in mysql, if thats the way to get date and time. How can I achieve that?