# How often must timezone be set for a php web application, using mysql's session time-zone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I might be lazy, but this question seems easier to just ask than to go laborating for.
I have been able to set time-zone with mysql cli, with the query

```
SET @@session.time_zone = "+01:00";
```

I wonder, for a php web application (that keeps a users time-zone), how often must this query be made. Is it for every connection to the MySql/MariaSql database engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some googling and it showed that the setting of time-zone for a web-app having users in different time zones - is done at every db connect.

```
$offset = "+01:00";
$db->exec("SET time_zone='$offset';");
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/

This question is actually deeper, and involves the field-type in the db, should it be TIMESTAMP or Datetime.

**NB**
I found by reading - and by some experience, that *it's better to let the timezone setting rest upon PHP*, and letting the MySql db be unaware of timezones... keeping db to GMT.

See this for reference:
[PHP, MySQL and Time Zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768380/php-mysql-and-time-zones)